# On windows download file at custom path using Selenium WebDriver is not working using ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I am using following code to download CSV file and its working properly on MAC but on Windows its not working.

On window it download file but it save it in download folder i.e. default path

```
    def self.launch(browser=:firefox, profile=nil)
        profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
        path = File.join(File.join(Dir.pwd), 'csv_files')
        FileUtils.rm_rf(path) if  Dir.exists? path
        Dir.mkdir(path)
        profile['browser.download.dir'] = path
        profile['browser.download.folderList'] = 2
        profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = 'text/csv'
        profile['pdfjs.disabled'] = true
        $watir_browser = UITest.new_browser_session browser, profile
        $driver = $watir_browser.wd
        return $watir_browser
      end
```

Please suggest me if any changes are required.

Comment: They are default settings. If you try to Save As, then you can set your custom path.

Comment: @Sham I am using custom path in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

When you do the line:

```
path = File.join(File.join(Dir.pwd), 'csv_files')
```

The path will be:

```
'some/path/csv_files'
```

In Windows, the "/" needs to be "\":

```
'some\path\csv_files'
```

**Solution**

What you can do is replace the slashes when the platform is Windows:

```
path = File.join(File.join(Dir.pwd), 'csv_files')
path.gsub!("/", "\\") if Selenium::WebDriver::Platform.windows?
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this else let me know.

```
relative_path = File.expand_path File.dirname(__FILE__)
```

OR

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
 path = File.join(File.join(Dir.pwd), 'csv_files')
    Dir.mkdir(path) unless File.exists?(path)
    modified_path = path.gsub!("/", "\\") if Selenium::WebDriver::Platform.windows?
    File.delete(File.join(modified_path, 'test.csv')) if File.exist?(File.join(modified_path, 'test.csv'))
    open(File.join(modified_path, 'test.csv'), 'wb') do |file|
      file << open('http://example.com').read
    end
```